# Gradle sync failed: Cause: com/android/build/gradle/BaseExtension

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin

I downloaded a project from github and then tried to build it.

But, once Gradle ran, the event log of Android Studio (2.3.3) showed me this:

```
Gradle sync failed: Cause: com/android/build/gradle/BaseExtension
Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

And also

```
Error:(18, 0) com/android/build/gradle/BaseExtension
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\Gustavo\AndroidStudioProjects\simpletask-android\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

[image]

It seems like Gradle couldn't find Kotlin in the right spot but I don't know how to change this.

Kotlin is installed and updated (to version 1.1.3).

[image]

It is also configured as a dependency of the "app" module in the project.

[image]

But, as the last image shows, the version of the external library that the project sees is 1.0.6 and not 1.1.3.

[image]

Is that the problem?
How can I change this external library?

Comment: Did you add kotlin android extensions plugin to your gradle files ?

Comment: Yes, they were already there.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I had to put everything into `app/build.gradle` (and not the root build.gradle):

```
    dependencies {
         classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```

If I put the block above in the root `build.gradle`, I get the same error as you...

Comment: This is the correct answer. Dont know why android studio mistakenly inserted these lines in wrong gradle file.

Comment: How can you put `classpath` into your **app/build.gradle**?

Comment: Not sure what was the exact problem anymore.... You can put `classpath` nested inside a `buildScript` block if needed though

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @mbonnin, but in the opposite direction, I had to move the build tools dependency from `app/build.gradle` to the root `build.gradle`.

```
dependencies {
  classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta6'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in build.gradle(app level)

first

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

Second under dependencies

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
```

EDIT

Do this is project level gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3'
    ext.android_plugin_version = '2.2.0-alpha4'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

and at app level gradle

```
android {
 dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when I wanted to add Hilt dependencies.

Code below was part of my android project's root build.gradle file.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.7.10"
    ext.hilt_version = "2.38.1"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hilt_version"
    }
}
```

for me,after i added `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'` to the dependencies block, the problem was solved.

After adding,below code is the whole buildscript block

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.7.10"
    ext.hilt_version = "2.38.1"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        //you should change the version to the one that suits your project 
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hilt_version"
    }
}
```